# Is there a regex to replace all occurences except for the first one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, regexp-replace

I already tried to use this for above mentioned intention

```
var str = "48abc5,2d25.,ft87";
str = str.replace(/[^\d(,.)?]/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

I expected the output would be **485,225**
because of the 0-1 condition through the question mark.

However my output is **485,225.,87**

Simply my final approach is to have a number seperated by comma or a dot.
Following pattern would fit my intention:

***{1-9}+{0-9)?{, | . }{1-9}****

Would love to hear your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside character classes, all chars are literal, except for `^`, `\`, `[` and `-`. So, you cannot add `?` there and expect it to behave as a quantifier.

You need

```js
var str = "48abc5,2d25.,ft87";
str = str.replace(/[^\d,.]+/g, '').replace(/^([^.,]*(?:[.,][^.,]*)?).*/, '$1').replace(/^0+/, "");
console.log(str);
```

The `.replace(/[^\d,.]+/g, '')` part removes all chars other than digits, dots and commas.

The `.replace(/^([^.,]*(?:[.,][^.,]*)?).*/, '$1')` part keeps the first steak of digits and optionally a second streak of digits after the first `.` or `,`.

The `.replace(/^0+/, "")` part removes one or more `0` digits at the beginning of the string.

Your fixed demo fiddle:

```js
function testRegex(event){
    let evt = event || window.event
  console.log(evt.target.value)
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: "+ 
  evt.target.value.replace(/[^\d,.]+/g, '')
                            .replace(/^([^.,]*(?:[.,][^.,]*)?).*/, '$1')
                              .replace(/^0+/, "");
}
```

```html
<label>Value:</label>
<input onkeyup="testRegex()" type="text"/>
<p id="result">Result:</p>
```

Comment: I added additional regex-replacement at the end, in order to remove the first character, when it's a zero. Will accept your answer, if the change is accepted. Thank you so much.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't filters if you type the characters one by one. I use it within an input field in html and it calls the method, where this regex is being executed, in its onKeyUp()-event...

Comment: @SercanSametSavran Please provide a demo fiddle/codepen/etc.

Comment: Sorrry for the late response. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sercan35/hzk2meyo/1/#&togetherjs=CoMGSRCkH6

Edit: It also doesn't take the first number.

Comment: @SercanSametSavran I think the issue was with `.+`. I replaced it with `.*`.